# App hangs when not being debugged in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have this app which authenticates a user with external web service and should navigate to a different view once authenticated.

The authentication is done in a HttpWebRequest:

```
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://webservice");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(CheckLogin), request);
    }
```

Then here is the callback:

```
    private void CheckLogin(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        bool success = false;

        try
        {
            // End the operation
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
            if (responseString.Contains("ok"))
            {
                success = true;
            }

            streamResponse.Dispose();
            streamRead.Dispose();
            response.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        request.Abort();
        request = null;

        if (success)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(Main2));
            }).AsTask().Wait();
        }
    }
```

This is working perfectly when debugging in Visual Studio but when I have published the application and installed the package, it hangs on Frame.Navigate. I guess this is because the CheckLogin method is not running in the UI thread.

Any ideas on how to Frame.Navigate(..) in a background thread?

Comment: Why want you navigate in an async way ?

Comment: I have also tried to skip the Dispatcher.RunAsync(...); and calling Frame.Navigate directly but it not working either.

Comment: Can you provide more code, so I can understand how your thread is created / how CheckLogin is called?

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for looking into this. I have updated the code to include more details.

Comment: It seems to be no real problems between `Dispatcher.RunAsync` and `Frame.Navigate`. So I assume we're not looking in the right direction. When you say that don't hangs in debugging, are you in debug or release mode ?
Try to also look at an override of `OnNavigatedTo` in your `Main2` which dont call `base.OnNavigatedTo()`

Comment: Everything is working while running in Visual Studio, both in Debug and Release mode but when I install the package (even on the same computer) this causes the app to crash. I'll check the OnNavigatedTo override.

Comment: Have you details of the exception ? Maybe the `Dispatcher` (after deploy optimisation) isn't the good one (while `this.Dispatcher` is specified). Try with `Frame.Dispatcher` ?

Comment: Thanks Nicolas! Turns out this didn't have anything to do with Frame.Navigate. The app crashed when the Main2 frame was loaded because of a code apparently faulty when the app is running after being installed as package but not faulty in Visual Studio.

Comment: What was this code ? I'm curious ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it may be empty while loops used to wait for HttpRequests to complete (to avoid async callbacks). This can be fixed by putting await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)); into the loops but it's not ideal to wait for the HttpRequests like this so I'm going to rewrite the code to use async callbacks everywhere.

Comment: I maybe not provided a real answer but a little upvote would be apreciated ! ;-)

Comment: I would definitely upvote your answer but you seem to have removed it so I can't. Can you add it again?

Comment: Oops ;)
Un-removed, and edited to point-out the real problem, for futures visitors.
Note that comments are upvote-able too, that's why I have let my post deleted ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be no real problems between Dispatcher.RunAsync and Frame.Navigate. So I assume you're not looking in the right direction.

Maybe your page's content is faulty, instead of the navigation.

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke doesn't exist. The only way I have been able to use the Dispatcher is using Dispatcher.RunAsync(..)

Comment: Ok, my fault. now  I understand, your method is executed on an other thread and you want to Invoke the navigation call. I'll edit my post